# Middleware Log Grpc Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, grpc-c#

I have asp.net grpc service with middleware to block bad user Ip.
I would like to log bad user grpc request, at the moment i can access only with headers, body look like not work.

```
public BlackIpService(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<BlackIpService> logger)
{
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
}

public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
  var currentIp = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();
  if (BlackListIp.TryGetValue(currentIp, out var requestFailed))
  {
     var requestContent = new StringBuilder();

     requestContent.AppendLine($"method = {context.Request.Method.ToUpper()} " + $"path = {context.Request.Path}");
      foreach (var (headerKey, headerValue) in context.Request.Headers)
      {
          requestContent.AppendLine($"header = {headerKey}    value = {headerValue}");
      }
                    /*
                    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
                    var requestReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);
                    var content = await requestReader.ReadToEndAsync(); //not work with GRPC
                    requestContent.AppendLine($"body = {content}");
                    */
      _logger.Log("BlackList", "Ip " + currentIp + " " + requestContent.ToString());
       context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
       return;
  }
 await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

Comment: gRPC isn't a simple single-stream transport; capturing body payloads would require a lot more than you might expect; you might consider a gRPC interceptor instead, perhaps? (gRPC has an API specifically for things like adding logging into the pipeline)